# python tkinter mouse left click works only with double click

Tags: python, button, events, tkinter, bind

With the below code `Button-1` click called `relief` change works only when it is already clicked once (only double click works 1st time, 2nd time it is ok, but if an other widget is selected, the same happens):

```
def selected(event):
    event.widget.config(relief=SUNKEN if event.widget.cget("relief") == "raised" else RAISED)    

B1 = Button(root, text ='BUTTON1', font='-size 8', relief=RAISED)
B1.bind("<Button>", selected)
B1.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = N+E+S+W)

B2 = Button(root, text ='BUTTON2', font='-size 8', relief=RAISED)
B2.bind("<Button>", selected)
B2.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = N+E+S+W)
```

With Button-2 and Button-3 it is working properly,

**What is the reason?**

Comment: first use `print()` to check what you get `event.widget.cget("relief")` when you click it. Second: create minimal working code with your problem which we can test.

Comment: Try adding `return 'break'` in `select()` function.

Comment: code works correctly when I use `command=` instead of `bind()`. I think it can be the problem - `tkinter` already uses `<Button>` with `command=` and it can makes some conflict. Using `return 'break'` in `bind()` (mentioned by @acw1668) it can block other function and block conflict.

Comment: try saying `def selected(event=None):`

Comment: Actually you can use `Checkbutton` with `indicator=False` which has the same effect.

Comment: @furas I tried the `print()` before, it was correct. The `command=` is not working here for me, because originally I generated lots of buttons with for loop and it always changed the last one's relief only. The `return 'break'` solved my problem, thank you. Could you describe this deeper how does it work?

Comment: @CoolCloud Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Actually I just think that the default mouse button release event handler may mess up the synchronisation of the relief state.  But why it works on second click, and then it does not work after clicking another button, I don't know the reason.  `return "break"` just skip the default event handlers.  Once again, I prefer using `Checkbutton` with `indicator=False`.

Comment: @acw1668 Now I can see that `Checkbutton` solves my problem, too. With setting `indicator = 0` or `False` it looks like a normal `Button` (indicatoron = ... works, too). Thank you for both solutions.

Comment: if you create buttons in loop then you need `lambda` in `command=(lambda arg=button:selected(arg))`. You can see this solution in many questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @furas If I run it with `command=(lambda arg=button:selected(arg))` it doesn't know what button is, it has to be created 1st (button or B or on any name in for loop). If I try with `arg=x:selected(arg)`, it passes an integer and cannot use `cget` on it. If I create button 1st and configurate after with `.config` it only modifies last button once. If I try `lambda arg= x:selected(button)` it still modifies the last button only. This last one could work somehow, but I cannot see the whole picture.

Comment: @Solari even that I know the issue is solved. I would like to know if .bind('<<Click>>', *func) works.

Comment: @Atlas435 No, it doesn't even call the function. If I try with `<<anything>>` (literally and also figuratively) it doesn't give error, but it does the same.

Comment: I did remember about this code here, but maybe it doesn't work at all anymore. https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/event+generate

Comment: you have to assign button to `arg=` - you can't put it directly in `selected()` - `button['command'] = lambda arg=button:selected(arg)` All problem is that it doesn't copy value from `button` to `selected(button)` but only reference to variable `button` which is changed in loop so finally all `selected` use reference to the same value - last value in `for`-loop. Using `arg=button` it creates new variable in every loop and it copies value from `button` to `arg` - so every `selected()` use differen `arg` with different value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that `tkinter` can bind many functions to event and there is already binded default function which changed `relief` when you click button. You can use `return "break"` in your function to inform `tkinter` that you processed this event and it will skip other functions.

Or you could use standard `command=` to assing function and then it will skip other function.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
 
# --- functions ---

def selected1(event):
    event.widget.config(relief='sunken' if event.widget.cget('relief') == 'raised' else 'raised')    
    return "break"

def selected2():
    B2.config(relief='sunken' if B2.cget("relief") == 'raised' else 'raised')    

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

B1 = tk.Button(root, text='BUTTON1', relief='raised')
B1.bind("<Button>", selected1)
B1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='news')

B2 = tk.Button(root, text='BUTTON2', relief='raised', command=selected2)
B2.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='news')

root.mainloop()
```

The same using `for`-loop and `lambda`.

Normally it use only reference to `button` which valeu is changed in loop so finally all functions use reference to the same value - which is last value assigned in loop.

Using `lambda arg=button` it create new variable in every loop and copy value from `button` to `arg` so every widget use different arg with differen value.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
 
# --- functions ---

def selected(widget):
    widget.config(relief='sunken' if widget.cget('relief') == 'raised' else 'raised')    

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

for x in range(1, 6):
    button = tk.Button(root, text=f'LOOP BUTTON {x}', relief='raised')
    #button.config(command=lambda arg=button:selected3(arg))
    button['command'] = lambda arg=button:selected(arg)
    button.grid(row=x, column=2, sticky='news')

root.mainloop()
```

---

As @acw1668 mentioned in comment you can also uses `Checkbutton(..., indicator=False)` to get the same effect without extra function

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
 
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

for x in range(1, 6):
    button = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=f'LOOP BUTTON {x}', indicator=False, padx=10, pady=5)
    button.grid(row=x, column=2, sticky='news')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This way the for loop generated buttons work too. Thanks.

Comment: mark this as the correct ans, if it helped u solve the issue :D

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you just have to tweak a single thing in order to single-click on buttons to activate the function. Try changing the bind to this:

```
def selected(event):
    event.widget.config(relief=SUNKEN if event.widget.cget("relief") == "raised" else RAISED)    

B1 = Button(root, text ='BUTTON1', font='-size 8', relief=RAISED)
B1.bind("<Button-1>", selected)
B1.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = N+E+S+W)

B2 = Button(root, text ='BUTTON2', font='-size 8', relief=RAISED)
B2.bind("<Button-1>", selected)
B2.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = N+E+S+W)
```

Just change "Button" to "Button-1" and please tell me if there are errors

Comment: It doesn't work with <Button-1>, I tried and copied here with <Button>, because it shows that with middle and right button it works properly.

Comment: Try using `ButtonPress` instead of `Button=1`

Comment: It does the same.

Comment: it is the same `<Button>` , `<Button-1>`, `<ButtonReleased>`, `<ButtonReleased-1>` and almost the same as `<ButtonPressed>` and `<ButtonPressed-1>`. Problem is that tkinter can bind many functions to the same event and there is already binded (default) function which has to be stoped/skiped - and `return "break"` skips this second function.